# Using storyboards in xcode and the app store

Tags: ios, ios5, storyboard

I am in a process of learning ios development.  I am beginning to learn storyboards and i found out that its only IOS 5 compatible.  I searched here and found some answers but i wanted to find out if it make sense at this point to use storyboards.  How does application behave that requires 5.0 in the app store?  Does it show up for people that have 4.3 and lower?  When i look through new application i don't see any that says 5.0 required in the description. Does that mean most people do not use storyboards to develop apps yet?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: People are using storyboards, but the majority of apps in the app store were not built new, they are updated versions that were build for ios 3,4 or earlier.  I would recommend you use storyboards if you are making a new app.   However, if you want to target older 3g phones and old iPod Touches, then you cant use it, however those devices are disappearing, and I would recommend you do not target those devices.  Also, it will take some time to get your app written and in the app store, and who knows, there may even be another IOS between now and then, def use storboards and ARC, they help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

story board is available in SDK 4.2 with which you can build for iOS 5, you can certainly set your deployment target to 4.x and it will work like a charm..!!

Updated : as @FirozeLafeer told, I confirmed my knowledge that he is right - XCode displays a message that "storyboards are unavailable on iOS 4.3 or prior"

From Apple: `Storyboards are supported in iOS 5 and later and are enabled by default for new projects. If your app must run on earlier versions of iOS, though, you cannot use storyboards and should continue to use nib files.`

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/AppDesignBasics/AppDesignBasics.html

Comment: Not if the app uses a storyboard.

Comment: Thanks for the replies!  This means that if I develop an app using story boards and submit to the app store.  This app can be downloaded by users with IOS 4.3 and higher?

Comment: "unavailable on iOS 4.3 or prior" means os should be 5.0 or higher

Comment: Sorry i misread.  If a user opens the app store with IOS 4.3 and lower will that app show up in the store and if they download would it just crash?  Thanks!!!

Comment: it wont download. message will be displayed regarding minimum OS requirement.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you think it make sense to use storyboards right or there is a big loss of potential customers?